# Sign convention error in rotational mechanics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, conventions, torque

[image]
I was recently going through a question regarding the angular velocity of a rod-mass system as a function of angle rotated. Ive given down my working below. My question is, why does the term of angular velocity squared become negative? It is obviously wrong but whats wrong in my sign convention?

Here an arrangement of 2 equal masses connected by a light rod is kept on horizontal ideal surface. A force F is such that it is always directed in the downwards direction. Find angular velocity as a function of angular displacement.

At any angle theta, the torque about COM is:
Γ=Fl/2  cos⁡θ

Fl/2  cos⁡θ = Iα = 2m l^2/4 α

α=(F cos⁡θ)/ml=ωⅆω/ⅆθ

rearranging and integrating LHS from theta = 0 to some angle phi and RHS from ω = 0 to ω = W i get:

(-F)/ml  sin⁡ϕ= W^2/2

Which would mean that angular velocity would be a complex number!
Although the magnitude of the angular velocity is correct, where have gone wrong with the sign convention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*. . . . where have I gone wrong with the sign convention?* is difficult to answer as you have not stated what your sign convention is.

Using the chain rule $\frac {d\omega}{dt} = \omega\cdot \frac{d\omega}{d\theta}$ is fine.

However, it is nothing to do with your sign convention it is the fact that have mistakenly assumed that $\int\cos \theta \,d\theta = \color{red} {\large \bf -} \sin \theta + c$.

[image]

Let $F$ be the magnitude of the force, so $\vec F = F\,\hat y$.
The torque about centre of mass, $\tau = \vec r \times \vec F = \dfrac \ell 2\,\cos \theta\, \hat x\times F\,\hat y = \dfrac{F\ell\cos \theta}{2}\, \hat z $.

Thus, $I_{\rm com}\,\alpha \,\hat z = \dfrac{F\ell\cos \theta}{2}\, \hat z \Rightarrow \alpha = \dfrac{F\ell\cos \theta}{2\,I_{\rm com}}$ where $\alpha$ is the angular acceleration

which then on integration gives $\omega^2 = \dfrac{F\ell\sin\theta}{I_{\rm com}}$.

---

A simpler way is as follows.
Work done by external force is $F\,\frac{\ell}{2}\, \sin \theta$.
Using the work energy theorem, work done is equal to the change in the rotational kinetic energy of the system.

$\frac 12 \, I_{\rm com}\, \omega^2 - 0=F\,\frac{\ell}{2}\, \sin \theta$ as long as $180^\circ\le\theta\le 0^\circ$.

Comment: Ohhhhh.... how did i not see that error!!  Thanks very much!! I spent a lot of time going through this question but never bothered to check the integration again. Thanks for second method too.